# Is there a standard name for the following type of linear operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, matrix-theory

Is there a standard name for a linear operator $T$ on a finite dimensional vector space satisfying $T^n=T^{n+1}$ for some $n\geq 1$ or, equivalently, $T$ is a similar to a direct sum of a nilpotent matrix and an identity matrix?  I am not looking so much for name suggestions, but rather for a generally accepted terminology from the literature.

**Added Motivation.** In Kovacs proof that the complex algebra of the monoid of $n\times n$-matrices over a finite field is semisimple a key step is to show that the ideal of the monoid algebra spanned by the singular matrices is a unital ring. He shows that the identity is a linear combination of matrices satisfying the above property. He calls such matrices semi-idempotent. But I believe he invented the name.

Being a semigroup theorist I don't like math terms involving "semi" and so in my book I would prefer another term, preferably one in use in the matrix theory literature.

Comment: @Hyperplane, I wrote direct sum not sum, which is what you wrote.

Comment: my bad I overlooked that

Answer (score 2):

The closest term I know is "idempotent", though that's only for $n=1$.

Comment: But if n>1, it need not be idempotent. It could be nilpotent. Laci Kovacs calls them semi-idempotent by but I think he invented the term.

Comment: It's a shame that 'idempotent' came first, and was used only in the sense that you mention; it seems like it would be the perfect word for @BenjaminSteinberg's situation if it weren't already taken.  I know that the question specifically *doesn't* ask for suggestions, but it's hard to avoid imagining them:  'eventually idempotent'?  (That sounds like it's saying that some $T^n$ is idempotent, though.)  'Stabilipotent'?

Comment: @LSpice Eventually idempotent is a name I have been considering if an official name doesn't come up.  A good joke name is demi-potent since it is an anagram of idempotent

Comment: Sorry for reviving this but the term "eventual idempotence" is mentioned in this book: https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=tarCAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=%22eventually+idempotent%22&source=bl&ots=XHquwEFG7w&sig=ACfU3U3EgqLlAXBHPv-0yObmkNKMe_X7sQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwimhoKOrKXjAhUC06YKHXQ6CM8Q6AEwA3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22eventually%20idempotent%22&f=false

Comment: @kubuzetto, links to a Google preview do not always show the page you want

Answer (score 0):

I would call it projectipotent :)

Answer (score -1):

I would say "unipotent" is the standard term.

Comment: Really?  Wikipedia says a unipotent matrix $T$ would have $1$ as its only eigenvalue.  But the OP's matrices might have both $0$ and $1$.

Comment: In my experience, "unipotent" means "characteristic polynomial $(T-1)^n$", so $\mathrm{Id}+\mathrm{nilpotent}$.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer If you read the OP's question, that is exactly how he characterizes his operators :)

Comment: @IgorRivin if you read the OP's question, he said _direct_ sum!

Comment: Yes it is direct sum not sum. Only the identity can be unipotent and have my property.